# Construction of 2tape Turing machine

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, turing-machines

Let $\Sigma:=\{ 0,1, \textrm{#} \}$ and the language $L=\{ bin(n)\textrm{#}w \in \Sigma ^* \mid n \in \mathbb N \, \land \, w \in \{ 0,1 \}^* \land |w| \leq n \}$

$\mid w \mid $ is the length of the word $w$. How can one describe a 2 tape TM that exactly accepts words from L.

I would really appreciate help to understand "how L looks like".

First I thought L is a string like "1101" and in decimal this would be 13. And so $\mid w\mid \leq13$, but now I wonder that $\mid w\mid \leq n$ would hold for any $n \in \mathbb N$. I am missing something but I do not know what..

P.S. There is a hint to use a TM that subtracts one from a given string.

Comment: The string $11\#01$ would be in $L$, because $w=01$, $|w|=2$, $2 \leq 3$, and $\operatorname{bin}(3)=11$.

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi could you add some additional information. why did you choose 11#01? bin (3)=11 ok, # ok, but why 01?

Comment: so 11#001 would be also in L and 111#00000000 not. since bin(7)=111 and |w| =8 > 7

Comment: Yes, both your examples are correct.

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi thanks for help, now if I want to write a TM solving this problem, I do not see how one can construct one with running time in $ O(n)$. My idea is to copy the string right to # on the 2nd tape, and then I delete the last bit of this string while I reduce on the first tape the string left to # by one. I repeat this and will be able to solve the problem. But the running time in the worst case should be in $O(n^2)$. How could one construct a faster algorithm?

Comment: If you copy the part of the input string before the $\#$ to the second tape, it's a little neater, but I agree it's still $O(n^2)$.  Then again, how fast can you subtract one from a string that is the binary encoding of a positive integer?

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi I can subtract 1 from a string in $O (n)$ . Can you explain me how one could solve with this knowledge to solve this problem in $O (n)$?

Comment: Could you copy bin(n) to the second tape and then for each digit of w read, you subtract 1 from bin(n) on the second tape? Would that be O(n)?

Comment: but if $w=n $ then this is again in $O (n^2) $

Comment: I agree that you can subtract 1 in time linear in the length of the string. Hence if you "call the subtraction routine" a number of times that is not bounded by a constant, you don't get an overall linear time.